# How to omit joining of superclass in JPA when Im querying subclass only?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, optimization

I have a JPA model with class hierarchy. I use InheritanceType.JOINED strategy. My model:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class A {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

@Entity
public class SubA extends A {

    private String val;

    public String getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

}
```

JPA query

```
select val from SubA
```

generates this sql

```
select suba0_.val as col_0_0_ from SubA suba0_ inner join A suba0_1_ on suba0_.id=suba0_1_.id
```

There is a inner join to the superclass table, which is useless. I need nothing from there. Is there a way how to avoid that? Thank you!

(testet with Hibernate 5.2.15.Final)

Comment: I doubt that it is possible, but I might be wrong

Comment: If you need nothing from the base class why did you choose inheritence?

Comment: @simon, It depends on query. In some queries I need values only from subclass, in some I need values from both. The superclass in the question does not have any values, but it is only simplification of my real model, there the superclass is not empty.

Comment: there is no way to do that.